# How do I have one user define fields for another user to fill out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have one type of user creating form fields for a job posting. They can define the field type and name (eg. type:"string" and name:"job_title").

My question is how do I store this data so that the job form for the applicant user has all of these defined fields?

Currently the job and form template is organized like this:

- job BELONGS TO employer_template
- employer_template HAS MANY jobs
- employer_template HAS MANY template_fields

I've tried to search for solutions, but haven't seen anything that answers it clearly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid to create all those tables, it sounds an overengineered solution.

You could simply serialize the fields and the contents, and store them in just one field.
That is automatically done by **serialize**:

```
class employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :custom_fields
end
```

Simple and fast :)